# How to display and click on buttons in a specified location on the screen?

Tags: android, user-interface, screen

I have written an app that shows 3 ImageViews in specified locations and by clicking on these buttons the user can navigate through the app.
To do that, first I used Bitmaps, it worked well for all type of the screens, but the problem was the memory overhead so I changed my method.

here is my code: I place ImageViews with specified with and height (in dp) and use the method "getArea" to determine which Image the user clicks, the problem is that the app interface is different on several phones and specially tablets (it does not recognizes the clicks)
my question: isn't it that "dp" is pixel independent? shouldn't it be the same on all devices? what is your suggestion in my case?

MainLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.arghavan.lenovo.autismo.main.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/main_page_background"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/balloon"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/main_page_balloon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rainbow"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/main_page_rainbow"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sun"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/main_page_sun"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sound_icon"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

      />

</FrameLayout>
```

in MainActivity:

```
public void onTouch (View v, MotionEvent ev)
{
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();


    // If we cannot find the imageView, return.
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById (R.id.image);
    if (imageView == null) return false;

    switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            int area =  getArea(evX,evY);

            if (area==1)
            {

                //do something
            }

            else if (area==2)
            {
                //do something
            }

            else if (area==3)
            {
               //do something
            }


            break;

        default:
                //do something

    } // end switch
}




private int getArea(float x, float y)
{
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float rx = x / density;
    float ry = y / density;

    if( 20< rx && rx<196 && 15<ry && ry< 159 )
        return 1;
    if( 86< rx && rx<293 && 138<ry && ry< 384 )
        return 2;
    if( 224< rx && rx<352 && 13<ry && ry< 141 )
        return 3;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use three imageview with changing its visibility on user click and perform action by getting image's id?

Comment: @Tejas Pandya: can you describe it more, my aim is to place imageView in a specified location on screen.

Comment: Why you are using onTouchListener? Can't you use onClickLisnteners?

Comment: @Mohammad Asheri: yes i can, when i want to make the whole image clickable, but what if i want to make only part of the image clickable(for example only center of the image)?